# Compile Error: Expected Array - VBA

Tags: vba

Could anyone please explain what is the reason for this error? The code looks totally fine to me.

```
Public n As Long, i As Long, prodCode As String
Private Sub newArray()

    n = wsProducts.Range("A1", wsProducts.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    ReDim prodCode(n)

    For i = 1 To n
        prodCode(i) = wsProducts.Range("A1").Offset(i, 0)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You have declared `prodCode` as a string, but not an array of strings

Comment: `prodCode() As String`

Comment: @YowE3K thank you! That was so easy!

Comment: BTW - If you declare `prodCode() As Variant` (or, in this case, even as `prodCode As Variant`) you can then get rid of the `ReDim` statement by replacing the loop with `prodCode = Application.Transpose(wsProducts.Range("A1:A" & n))`

Answer (score 1):

You have declared prodCode as a string, but not as an **array** of strings.

You need to use `prodCode() As String` if you wish to use that variable as an array.

---

Note: You can also speed your code up by using a Variant array, which allows you then to "load" the array in one transfer operation:

```
Public n As Long, prodCode() As Variant
Private Sub newArray()

    n = wsProducts.Range("A1", wsProducts.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    'P.S. That statement would simplify to 
    'n = wsProducts.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    prodCode = Application.Transpose(wsProducts.Range("A1:A" & n)

End Sub
```

`Application.Transpose` has been used to change the shape of the array from being a `1 To n, 1 To 1` two-dimensional array to being a `1 To n` one-dimensional array.